# Codeforces compiler shows a different output than Code::Blocks (Question 282A - Bit++)

Tags: c, int, codeblocks

I've been trying different compilers available on the Codeforces submission page but none of the different compilers is giving an output such as Code::Block's

Problem link: https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/282/A

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
int count = 0, i = 0, final;
int x = 0;
char strg[3];

scanf("%d", &count);

for (i = 0; i < count; i++){
    scanf("%s", &strg[0], &strg[1], &strg[2]);
    if ((strcmp(strg,"x++") == 0) || (strcmp(strg,"++x") == 0)){
        x = x+1;
    } if ((strcmp(strg,"x--") == 0) || (strcmp(strg,"--x") == 0)){
        x = x-1;
    }
}
printf("%d", x);
```

}

Submission page output: "wrong answer 1st numbers differ - expected: '1', found: '0'"
However, Code::Blocks prints the correct value which is "1".

Codeforces submission:

[image: Codeforces compiler output]

Program running output:

[image: Running the code from codeblocks]

Comment: A C string is limited by a final end-of-string character `'\0'`. But since your variable has only space for 3 characters, the used test checker might put anything after the third character. -- Another quirk: Why are you providing three target arguments for just one format specifier at your call of `scanf()`? Additionally, you should check its return value.

Comment: I checked the return value and it's just the same as the printf() output, could you please further clarify what I should do?

Comment: Well, the return value of `printf()` has a completely different meaning than the return value of `scanf()`. Please read its documentation. -- Another thing to consider: Are you sure that "x" is lower case?

Comment: You might like to print the read instruction to see what you got, for example like this: `printf("\"%s\"\n", strg);`

Comment: I tried printing the read line as using the statement you mentioned, it showed the inputted result but it was between quotation marks, does that make a difference? and has "x" is lower case when inputted

Comment: I realized the double quotes are from the statement you gave me.

Comment: Yes, this is a good method to see whether there are any whitespace characters. You could use any other character, but double quotes are nice for strings. -- So you found that the input is lower case and presumably "++" or "--" before or after it. The next step would be to `printf("%d %d %d %d\n", strcmp(strg,"x++"), strcmp(strg,"++x"), strcmp(strg,"x--"), strcmp(strg,"--x"));`.

Answer (score 1):

The `strg[3]` is too short to accommodate the 2 chars string. It is an Undefined Behaviour.

As it is undefined it works in some environment and does not in another.

Comment: I changed the 3 to a 10 and still no difference.